# Very difficult decision on a suggested edit

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22892057

Screenshot:

[image]

So, I am just not sure because at least 63 people liked this 8 years old answer without removing this funny smiley. Of course I know where the "Skip" button is, but I would like to ask what you will do with this edit? And in general, what you will do with other such stuff that doesn't improve quality of a post but was on SO for a long time for some historical reasons?

Comment: The image wasn't there from the beginning. Answer posted: Jun 21 '11. Image added: Jun 13 '18. Imho, the edit should be accepted since it removes fluff (and there have been other changes since then).

Comment: Oh, didn't check time of uploading the picture. It slightly changes the situation. And yes, if I don't have "Skip" button I would accept this edit.

Comment: It's worrying that reviewers have to wonder in clear open and shut cases like this.

Comment: I liked the kissing smiley though.

Comment: While we are at the topic of looking at the post can someone with python knowledge clarify meaning of "Warning, pros only:" in that post - is dangerous as in "performed by trained professionals on closed course, don't try it at home" or something else? Some reasoning would be nice

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I think the author threw in that phrase because he considers it quite advanced and "magic". The double-underscore methods are *usually* not used much in day-to-day code. Note that the author himself did not use `__getitem__` in the original formulation of his answer. He only added it after someone commented that it could be done that way. Also note that probably not all Python programmers would have put in that "warning", even as a joke. (And it does seem to at least be partly lighthearted, given that it accompanied the addition of the image in question.)

Comment: *And in general, what you will do with other such stuff that doesn't improve quality of a post but was on SO for a long time for some historical reasons?* Although an entire question can get a historical lock, individual lines of code, text, or images aren't kept for historical reasons in unlocked posts. You don't have to worry about the age of content within a post when deciding whether or not it should be removed. Sometimes stuff just gets missed and/or the people seeing the post just don't bother editing to fix/remove it.

Comment: @BDL Who added it, was it the original author or some other user?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov agreed with John Y. This is not dangerous code, just obfuscated code. It's not even a preferred style (`[i for i, val in sorted(enumerate(MyList), key=lambda i_val: i_val[1])]` is better)

Comment: @dwirony: The original author. Nevertheless, it shouldn't have been added in first place.

Comment: "*Very difficult decision on a suggested edit... NOT!*"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That's noise as well. I've removed it.

Comment: Someone other than the original answerer added that image to the post. I'm curious about why that edit was approved—the person who did it doesn't have enough rep to have edited without approval. Why wasn't it rejected as vandalism?

Comment: @camille it was added by the original answerer in edit 3. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6423325/3. Edit 4 just hyperlinked the image. Possibly something done automatically by the UI. though the text change that was the rest of the edit should probably have been rejected as "no improvement"

Comment: What is next up? *"Extremely difficult decision"*? *"Mind-boggling difficult decision"*? *"Extremely difficult mind-boggling decision"*?

Comment: @Sanyash It doesn't matter if it was added 8 years ago or not. It doesn't matter if it was added by the answer's OP or not, I would've approved that edit in a heartbeat as the image adds no value whatsoever to the answer. _That_ is what matters.

Comment: @Cerbrus Although that line looks quite "noisy", it actually has some meaning (see [the comment above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384409/very-difficult-decision-on-a-suggested-edit#comment692396_384409)), so I'd rather not deleting it. Of course it's not as valuable as an actual explanation.

Comment: The revision 2 should be clearer with the use of lambda (however the answerer *removed* the information with the `__getitem__` version; however [the `__getitem__` version is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021755/5267751))

Comment: I'm the original author / question answerer. It was just some lighthearted fun, was interesting I got way more upvotes after adding that image. Happy to have it edited out to keep it clean.

Comment: @robertking Sidenote: when you add an image, change the alt text from _"enter image description here"_ to something that's actually useful & meaningful. The instruction should be clear enough.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

How many votes the answer had is irrelevant.

This doesn’t seem like a difficult decision to me. Cleaning up the post like that is undoubtedly a good edit. The noise to signal ratio decreases significantly by removing that image.

Approving is the way to go.

(It was approved by two other users since you posted this question).

Comment: I would also remove the "Warning, pros only:" comment and ask them to add some explanation

Comment: I don't know about that, what if he wants a professional opinion on it?

Comment: @RileyCarney: 1) Stack Overflow isn't really the place for such restrictions, and 2) your question itself proves that the comment is ambiguous.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should leave the content as is.  While the sound-to-noise ratio is lessened, I think the overall user experience of the site takes even more damage.  The trade-off is not worth it from a user perspective.

Most organizations go through similar steps.  At first, it's a free-for-all.  Many interesting things are tried.  Eventually, it turns out that rules are needed, and so they come into existence.  Then there's a period of refining the rules.

But the next step is one I've seen really cut the soul out of some groups, which is applying present rules to the past.

I think, given the context, it is nice to look back and say: "Hey, remember when SO was small enough people could get away with this.  If we did it now, it'd be awful though."

Leaving it does not imply in any way that the act is acceptable, but erasing it further buries the reality which is that (if it could) Stack Overflow would have a lot more chaos and fun.  That this is a fun place with rules meant to keep it working, rather than an everything-is-serious ordeal.

In short, removing the more playful parts of Stack Overflows past is akin to hiding it's inner child, and is an act more of forced seriousness than maturity (IMO).

As a soundbite: "Grown-up is a game children play"

Comment: *Leaving it does not imply in any way that the act is acceptable...* There are meta questions where people use 5+ year old posts to argue that their recent post should not have been edited/downvoted/closed/deleted.

Comment: That's a very fair point.  Still, it's a lame argument from the arguer (the one mad about their post), and punishing a group for the act of an individual (Collective Punishment) is generally not a great approach.  From this perspective, it matters more simply whether or not people feel it would be a loss to remove it.  And I do, but I'm just one person.